# Will the gem -https://github.com/cequel/cequel (that itself uses https://github.com/datastax/ruby-driver) work with DSE 6.0?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

Will the gem https://github.com/cequel/cequel (that itself uses https://github.com/datastax/ruby-driver)  work with DSE 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

As I see in the `gemspec` file, it requires `cassandra-driver ~> 3.0`. The existing 3.x cassandra-driver should be compatible with DSE 6.0, so `cequel` should continue to work with it.